# Program with many shared libraries won't start -- cannot allocate symbol search list: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: c, memory, linker, shared-libraries, ubuntu-20.04

I am currently trying to start a huge program that has many shared libraries (10000+). I know this is rather untypical, but we are doing huge calculations that require a lot space. We had to split the binary in multiple parts, because compilation would have taken forever and binaries larger >2GB make more trouble (see `mcmodel=large`). We are expecting that our program runs for a couple of days. The binary + shared libraries are around 50GB. I am on huge compute server with 128 cores and 1TB of RAM. When I start my binary I can see that it quite fast allocates a lot of RAM in htop (around 45GB), which is totally fine and expected. However after a couple of seconds the process stops and prints the following error:

`./Vchip: error while loading shared libraries: cannot allocate symbol search list: Cannot allocate memory`

Neither the disk nor the RAM are close to being full, so I do not understand the error.

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04. The entire code has been compiled with g++/gcc. The filesystem allows execution (noexec is not set in `/etc/fstab`).

Comment: That error comes from a failure to malloc memory while loading the shared libraries. Have you checked for kernel messages? Have you checked that there isn't a `ulimit` setting getting in the way?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We tried to allocate 500GB of memory. I don't think the ulimit is it. From looking at the source code the error probably stems from the glibc (dl-deps.c). Not sure how to proceed from here...

Comment: (we allocated the memory with malloc)

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently trying to start a huge program that has many shared libraries (10000+). I know this is rather untypical, but we are doing huge calculations that require a lot space

The system I work on uses 10-15K shared libraries as well. This works, but there are various system-level limits which may need to be adjusted.

One such limit is `vm.max_map_count`, which controls how many separate `mmap`s you can create on the entire system. Default is usually 64K.

With 10K libraries, you may need 30K or 40K separate mappings (depending on how many `LOAD` segments your libraries have) just to map all the libraries, which doesn't leave much headroom for heap allocations (which require mappings of their own).

---

Your explanation of *why* you need so many libraries doesn't make any sense though. I *suspect* that you need so many libraries because each library defines some (large) global array. If so, you should allocate them on the heap instead -- a program using (say) 5 shared libraries can easily allocate and use 100s of GiB of data.

> I don't think the ulimit is it.

Why not? What is the output of `ulimit -a`?